# Trying to load dataset inside flat_map got error 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load data saved using tensorflow.data.experimental.save method. I am getting this exception 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor'. I am using below code. How to convert tensor to file path string?

```
filenames = ["data4/0/31", "data4/0/32"]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
def parse_fn(filename):
  print(filename)
  return tf.data.experimental.load(filename)
dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x:
    parse_fn(x),
    cycle_length=4, block_length=16)

for item in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(item)
```